# How to correctly use vector<uint8_t>.data()?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

`vector.data()` should return a pointer to the first element, but when I use it on a `vector<uint8_t>`, it somhow returns somthing else:

```
int main() {
    std::string myString = {"a b c all the way long"};
    std::vector<uint8_t> myVec(myString.begin(), myString.end());
    std::cout << myVec.data() << std::endl;
    
    std::vector<int> anotherVec = {4,5,2,3}; 
    std::cout<< anotherVec.data() << std::endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

program prints:

```
a b c all the way long
0x124bf00
```

Why does the first print show all of the vector, and the second print shows the pointer? I was expecting both to print a pointer.

The real issue is that on another big program, when I print `vector<uint8_t>.data()` with `cout`, it prints garbage after it (when I look at it in the debugger, I don't see the garbage).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) function returns a pointer to the first element.

`myString` is a vector of `uint8_t` values, so `data()` will return a value of type `uint8_t*`. `uint8_t` is a type based on `char`, so the `<<` stream output operator will treat it as a null-terminated string. The problem here is that `myVec` doesn't contain a null-terminated string, so this is technically *undefined behavior*.

For `anotherVec`, that's a vector of `int` values, which means that `data()` returns a value of type `int*`, which has no specific overload for the `<<` stream output operator. Instead, it uses the closest possible overload, which is the one to print generic pointers of type `void*`.

If you want the first to print the pointer itself, then you need to explicitly cast the pointer to `void*`:

```cpp
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(myVec.data()) << '\n';
```